# How does make config command work

Tags: makefile, gnu, android-source, samsung-mobile, kbuild

In an effort to understand the configuration tools of the make build environment, I like to ask given the following config parameters:

```
make VARIANT_DEFCONFIG=msm8974_sec_hlte_spr_defconfig msm8974_sec_defconfig SELINUX_DEFCONFIG=selinux_defconfig
```

What does each of them do or mean please? I did a search for the `msm8974_sec_hlte_spr_defconfig` in my build environment and posted the result [here](http://pastebin.com/X2DRdiN4) I then looked for the configs, which are relevant to my handset, and I got about 20 or so. But I like to know what are the following please?

```
msm8974_defconfig
msm8974-perf_defconfig
msm8974_sec_defconfig
msm8974_sec_eng_defconfig
msm8974_sec_userdebug_defconfig
```

That is if I select them, what do they add or remove from my current config. I know that debug is for debugging and I am not sure what is the purpose of eng. I am looking to see what additional details I can find out please.

Also why are there two parameters for the VARIANT_DEFCONFIG parameter? What I mean is right after the variable there are two values specified as follows: `msm8974_sec_hlte_spr_defconfig msm8974_sec_defconfig` Does that mean I can add as many of them as I want? What is the syntax for this please?

Comment: The value of `VARIANT_DEFCONFIG` is *only* `msm8974_sec_hlte_spr_defconfig` in that command. Similarly the value of `SELINUX_DEFCONFIG` is `selinux_defconfig`. `msm8974_sec_defconfig` is an argument on its own (the make target to build).

Comment: What each of those targets/variable values does isn't something that we can answer. It is a part of the make environment/setup.